# Can't find exact Part type of Stepper Motor Driver

Tags: stepper-motor

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find the exact model/part number for this Stepper Motor Driver.
[image]

Comment: Neither can we. We can't read the number on the chip. Can you?

Comment: It may be an ULN2003, but thats pure speculation

Comment: @chrisl Looking at the pinout and wiring (what can be seen of it), you may be spot on there. Ground and + are in the right location, certainly.